# Fastest method to find a complex type in a list (Vector, Array, Dictionary, whatever is faster)

Tags: actionscript-3, performance, object-pooling

Hail, Stack!

I need to know the best method to find an item inside a list (Vector, Array, Dictionary, whatever is faster) of complex type (extensions of Objects and Sprites).
I've used "Needle in Haystack" method, but it seems that it isn't fast enough.

---

E.g.
Suppose that I have a collection of *Sprites* (a pool, in fact).
Each sprite will be added to the stage and perform some action. After that, it will die.
I don't want to pay the cost to dispose it (garbage collect) and create another (new) one every time so I'll keep the dead sprites in a collection.

Sometimes times I'll call a method that will add a sprite to the stage.
This sprite can be a old one, if it is already dead, or a new one, if the pool don't have any free sprite.

---

One of the scenarios that pushed me to this question was a Particle System.
A "head" particle leaving a "trail" of particles every frame and exploding into a flashy multitude of particles... Every frame...

Some times this counts up to 50.000 PNGs with motion, rotation, alpha, event dispatching, scale, etc...
But, this is JUST ONE scenario...

---

At the moment I'm trying to use a Object Pool with a Linked List...
Hopes that it will be faster that running a whole Array/Vector or create new instances every frame an let them dye with Garbage Collection.

Someone knows a better/faster way to do it?

Comment: Do you have any sort of key that can be attributed to the objects?(or possibly use the object as a key) I believe that a Dictionary look up would probably be the fastest. In that case you could just do `myDictionary[complexObject] != null`

Comment: @Mike, post this as an answer, so I can upvote it and, maybe, check as correct. =D Besides, I didn't tried to use the object as key yet (I thought that it would be slow), but I'll test right now...

Comment: Your question is too general. In order to do better than a linear (worst case O(n)) search on the list, you really need to know something about how the list gets populated, how many characteristics factor into the search, whether or not keys are unique, etc. If the problem is one where you're given an unsorted list, that is different than if you are the one who is storing the data and have total control over what type of data structure to use. You can speed up the retrieval of anything by doing more work at the time you put it into the list (e.g. keeping it sorted, using a hash function, etc)

Comment: @NemoStein I have now put it as an answer, we could probably help more if you are able to expand a bit more on what Adam has stated above

Comment: Agreement with Mike and Adam. I can't tell whether you're trying to look up an element in a container class, or whether you're trying to find the *type* of the element within the container array. The only reason I'd imagine you mean the former is because you included a Vector in your question, which is strongly typed, but that could ahave just been a mistake. Please clarify.

Comment: I added an answer below, now that I better understand the problem. I don't see the choice of data structure being the key issue here,  but rather efficient tracking of the items that are inactive and waiting to be re-used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your revised question, I don't see this as a search optimization issue unless we're talking about thousands of objects. When one of your objects from the pool "dies", it could notify your code that is managing the objects (by event or callback) and you then null out its entry in your Dictionary of active items (or splice it from Array, or kill it with a flag, more on this below**), and push it onto another Array, which is a stack of objects waiting to be reused. When you need a new object, you first check if there is anything in your recycle stack, and if there is, you pop one of those and re-initialize it. If the stack is empty, you construct a new one.

**The best choice of which data structure you use for holding your active objects list (Array/Vector/Dictionary) will probably depend on the nature of your list--I'd be willing to bet that the data structure that is quickest to loop over (for example if you need to do it every frame to update them) is not necessarily the one that is cheapest to delete from. Which one you go with should be whichever works best for the number of objects you've got and the frequency with which they get removed, re-added or updated. Just do a little benchmarking, it's easy enough to test them all. If you have relatively few objects, and don't need to loop over them continuously, I'd put my money on the Dictionary for the active pool.

The key point to get from this answer is that you should not be looping through all the items each time you need to find a dead one to re-use, you should pull them out when they die and keep that as a separate pool.

Comment: One of the scenarios that pushed me to this question was a Particle System.  A "head" particle leaving a "trail" of particles every frame and exploding into a flashy multitude of particles... Every frame... Some times, this counts up to 50.000 PNGs with motion, rotation, alpha, event dispatching, scale, etc... But, this is JUST ONE scenario...

Comment: Just to add a comment to my comment, I'm trying to use a Object-Pool with a Linked List atm... Hopes that it will be faster that running a whole Array or create new instances every frame an let them dye with Garbage Collection.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about what you are searching and what you want to do with it.
If you are trying to determine if a string is in a list, the fastest solution is the Dictionnary. I've done a little benchmark.

```
/**
* Determine which is the fastest to find a key between array, object, vector and dictionnary
**/
public class FlashTest extends Sprite {
    public function FlashTest() {
        var array:Array = new Array();
        var object:Object = new Object();
        var dictionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
        var vector:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();

        for (var i:int=0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            array.push(i.toString());
            object[i.toString()] = 1;
            vector.push(i.toString());
            dictionary[i.toString()] = 1;
        }

        var time:uint = getTimer();
        for (i=0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            array.indexOf(i.toString());
        }

        trace("array"+(getTimer()-time)); //2855

        time = getTimer();
        for (i=0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            vector.indexOf(i.toString());
        }

        trace("vector"+(getTimer()-time)); //3644


        time = getTimer();
        for (i=0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            object.hasOwnProperty(i.toString());
        }

        trace("object"+(getTimer()-time)); //48


        time = getTimer();
        for (i=0; i < 10000; i++)
        {
            dictionary.hasOwnProperty(i.toString());
        }

        trace("dictionary"+(getTimer()-time)); //35


    }
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Since the `Dictionary` inherits its `hasOwnProperty` from `Object`, I think they should give the same results... funny...

Comment: Why are you using so much l__ in your code? It looks much cleaner without it.

Comment: Haha! I've written this code for me in the first place so this is my personal syntax norm (actually the FBI's one). l__ stands for local, m__ for member, i__ for input...

Answer (score 1):

This is really going to depend on how you need to identify the object. Are you comparing some value of it or comparing references?

Assuming references, you should be using the built in methods found on both Array & Vector. Linear searches (like looping over the entire list) grow slower as the number of items in the list increases. The built in solutions will use faster non-linear search algorithms. For example:

```
myList.indexOf(myObject);
```

The fastest thing you can do is direct access. If you are using either an Object or Dictionary you can use the object or a unique id as the key, this gives you direct access. But this doesn't help if you need the objects position in the list. eg:

```
//when setting it
var map = {};
map[myObject] = myObject;
//or
map[myObject.id] = myObject;

//then later
var myObject = map[THE KEY]
```

Comment: Thanks, @Tyler. In fact, I don't need (ATM) of the index, and I can use any parameter as key (including the object itself). I won't compare values inside the object for now, so, the map can be a good choice (if it proves to be fast).

Comment: It is fast because you never have to loop over anything, its direct access. You should not be using a loop in that case.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any sort of key that can be attributed to the objects?(or possibly use the object as a key)

I believe that a Dictionary look up would probably be the fastest since it is done similar to Java's HashMap.

In that case you could have the object as the key and just do
`myDictionary[complexObject] != null` 
(it will be null if there is no entry of that object)
Although if you could specify further what it is you need to lookup I might be able to offer further application of this

Answer (score 0):

I'd say Vector, but there seems to be some mixed results.

[Vector.<> vs array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130309/vector-vs-array)

http://impossiblearts.com/blog/2008/06/fp10-vector-vs-array/

Comment: Thank you, @John... Vectors are, indeed, faster than Arrays for what I'm trying to do, but isn't fast enough yet. I'm looking for a faster/better way to search a list than simply `for(x in y)`.

Answer (score 0):

If your sprites have unique IDs, and you can use a Dictionary, then what's the question? Dictionary is definitely faster.

The average search on a Vector or Array takes, at best, O(log(n)) time. Though you can only achieve that if your Vector is sorted, which means spending time elsewhere to ensure it stays sorted. If you don't sort it then you have to scan, which means O(n).

Dictionaries (variously known as hashtables, maps), when implemented right (and I can only assume that what Actionscript provides is implemented right) guarantee O(1) access time. You pay for that in more memory. The O(1) hides some constant times that are higher than those of Vector searches, so for small lists of items Vector would be more efficient. However, from the description of your problem it sounds like a no-brainer.

Comment: I can't see the way to do it with Dictionary because I don't know beforehand which object is already dead. Should I implement another collection (a Vector) and keep a reference to the ID of the dead Object there or what?

Comment: I have no experience with ActionScript, so I may not understand your concept of a dead Object. However, you could keep another Dictionary that only contains your dead objects: the key is the Object ID and the value is whatever (e.g. a simple boolean True value). That second Dictionary functions as a Set where you can check whether a given object is dead, using its ID.