# Difference between list,vector and array in action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3

In action script many times I have come across the keywords 
1. array
2. list
3. vector

Please explain the difference between these three keywords?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vector.<> vs array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130309/vector-vs-array)

Comment: `list` or `List` is not a keyword

Answer (score 1):

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Arrays](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/arrays.html)

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Associative arrays, maps, and dictionaries](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/associative-arrays.html)

[ActionScript 3 fundamentals: Vectors and ByteArrays](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/vectors-and-bytearrays.html)